# Unicode escape characters not being read by XmlReader

Tags: c#, .net, xml, unicode

I've got an XML document that I'm importing into an XmlReader that has some unicode formatting I need to preserve.  I'm preserving the whitespace but it's dropping the encoded #x2028 which I assume should be expressed as a line break.

Here's my code:

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
                   {
                       ProhibitDtd = false,
                       XmlResolver = null,
                       IgnoreWhitespace = false
                   };

var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(fu.PostedFile.InputStream), settings);
var document = new XmlDocument {PreserveWhitespace = true};
document.Load(reader);
return document;
```

XML example:

```
<td valign="top" align="center">Camels and camel &#x2028;resting place</td>
```

How do I get to those characters to I can render br tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After importing the code into the reader I was able to find and replace that character:

```
Regex.Replace(s, "\u2028", "<br/>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear: do you expect the XmlReader to translate the `&#x2028;` into an HTML `<br>` tag? That isn't going to happen.

Or are you examining the actual character content of the `<td>` element (within the code, not as printed/displayed) and seeing "camel resting place"? If yes, please show the code that you're using to verify this, because it would be a pretty major bug.

Or something else?

Comment: I want to replace that Unicode point with a br tag.  I figured it out, thanks though.